# Spring security Login does NOT propagate my form(POST) to Controller

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

On Home page (permitAll() )

I have a form (Action "/saveX"   authenicated() )

I have a Controller with @PostMapping(value="/saveX")

User fills in form data & hits submit (POST)

Spring redirects to default login page

User enters username & password & hits login

User is now presented with Home page (logged-in features are now visible)

Was expecting Spring (successful)login to forward to my (@PostMapping)Controller

*Now that User is logged-In*

User fills in form data & hits submit (POST)

Controller with @PostMapping(value="/saveX") is invoked

**Question**
Shouldn't successful login result in continuing with the original action (ie my form POST)

NOTE - there will be many paths which could be the 1st reason for Authenticating the User --- so I won't have a default successfullogin link that can be used

I want to get these basics sorted out before I move on to implementing more sophisticated Authentication mechanisms - so will be replacing Spring default login later

Any help/hints greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by implementing AuthenticationSuccessHandler and need to extend SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler which will give you options on redirection decisions.

```
public class RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler 
  extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler
  implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    public RefererRedirectionAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        super();
        setUseReferer(true);
    }

}
```

In Spring Security configuration file, you need to register your AuthenticationSuccessHandler using successHandler() method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
      throws Exception {
        //put your logic here
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login*")
      .permitAll()
      .anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .successHandler(new RefererAuthenticationSuccessHandler());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have made both changes - login now takes User to login page (not Home page as previous)